# Getting the user location through in Android when the location is not changed.

Tags: android, gps

I am developing an Android applicaiton that tracks the user through GPS. I am able to get the location of the user when the location is changed by implementing the "onLocationChanged()" in every specified time and distance. But the problem is, i need to get the user location after every specified time even when the locationof the user is not changed. How can i accomplish this. Can you help me ?

Comment: you can use background thread, and call `onLocationChanged()` in that after the time you want it to be invoked.

Comment: Possible to duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352420/get-current-device-location-after-specific-interval

Comment: you can use LocationListener which gets called when your location get changed and moreover you can provide time interval too

Comment: The scenario is, sometime the user may move and other time user may sit at the same posotion. So i need to get the location after every specified time even when the user is not moving.