# Android - Getting user Current location in certain time interval

Tags: java, android

I need to get the user current location using gps in certain time interval even after closing the application. i have done using service.
here is my service class.

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "BOOMBOOMTESTGPS";
    private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
    private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 1000;
    private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 0f;

    private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener {
        Location mLastLocation;

        public LocationListener(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
            mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + location);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled" + provider);
        }
    }

    android.location.LocationListener[] mLocationListener = new android.location.LocationListener[]{
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER), new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
    };

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
        initializeLocationManagrr();
        try {

            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE, mLocationListener[0]);

        }catch(java.lang.SecurityException ex){
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex1){
            Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex1.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.e(TAG,"onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
        if(mLocationManager!=null){
            for(int i=0;i<mLocationListener.length;i++){
                try{
                    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener[i]);
                }catch ( Exception e2){
                    Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", e2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void initializeLocationManagrr(){
        Log.e(TAG,"initializeLocationManagaer");
        if(mLocationManager==null){
            mLocationManager=(LocationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }
    }
 }
```

And am calling this class from MainActivity.java like this

```
startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class));
```

and in  my Log nothing is shown regarding the location.

And also i have added the google service config files in my app.
My main problem is am not getting any user location in my Log cat but the app is running fine.

Can Anyone help me please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8352516/1406172

Answer (score 0):

you can use LocationListener which gets called when your location get changed and moreover you can provide time interval too

LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener(context);

mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1, 1,mlocL istener);

// **syntax**: mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, minTime, minDistance, listener)

you can set time and distance both in this method see ths syntax